# system calls and the internal flow

Tags: operating-system

Trying to understand the exact sequence of events in terms of flow in case of Linux:

1. User application program makes a call to a system call.
2. This results in execution of code which results in triggering of a software exception (which code is this? It's understandable if I called a glibc API, but what if my program is calling a system call directly). Is there some piece of code that regular system calls have which triggers this exception?
3. Once the exception is triggered -- user application processes context needs to be preserved and user application I presume will be in pend state(assuming its a waited system call that was invoked).
4. Exception handler then runs and picks suitable handler based on system call invoked(how is this system call number passed to exception handler from this exception triggering code?)
5. An exception handler runs(let's say a read call for example and has to return read data to use a process which triggered its invocation - this I assume would mean the exception triggering code has also passed a pointer to buffer to which read data needs to be copied over to)
6. Once the exception handler is done, the control now has to return to the application which would now be pending system call.

Does this flow look alright > Is there some sample code for each of these steps beyond user application?